# HTAccess Rewrite of URL to looklike Root based

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi Been searching for ages and tried a few examples but nothing is working. I want my URL to look as though it's located in the Root directory instead of the buy sub-directory:

```
http://www.example.com/buy/*.html
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/*.html

RewriteRule ^buy/(.*)$ $1 [L]
```

Keep getting page not redirecting correctly. @Panama Jack

Any ideas thanks.

.HTACCESS

```
# non-www to www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]


AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm


# rewrite products to root located    
RewriteRule ^buy/(.*)$ $1 [L]


# Remove index.php or index.htm/html from URL requests
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(([^/]+/)*)index\.(php|html?)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/)*index\.(html?|php)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]


# GZIP
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain text/html text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript


# Redirect all index calls
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.(php|html?)$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]


#Custom 404 errors
ErrorDocument 404 /productslinks404.html
```

Answer (score 0):

If `/buy/somepage.html` is a real page, then try your rule this way if you want

> http://www.example.com/page.html

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ /buy/$1.html [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have another rewrite of a dynamic url for the shop itself and now get a page not redirecting properly when I enter www.example,com/new.html, i.e. www.example.com/buy/buy/buy/buy/buy/buy/buy/buy/buy/buy/buy/buy/buy/buy/buy/buy/buy/buy/buy/buy/new.html

Comment: What are all your rules? Edit your question and add the contents of your htaccess file not just part of it.